# Is it possible to use cascades to operate on 2 properties of a variable?

Tags: dart

I want to return the length of the last word in a string. The words are separated by spaces.

```
return s.trimRight().length - s.trimRight().lastIndexOf(' ') - 1;
```

I want to remove the need to call `trimRight()` twice, and I was hoping cascades would help me to do that while keeping the solution a single line. But I tried something like this and it's not valid (for obvious reasons):

```
return (s.trimRight())..length - ..lastIndexOf(' ') - 1;
```

I know I can do it with an assignment operation, like so:

```
return (s = s.trimRight()).length - s.lastIndexOf(' ') - 1;
```

But my question is, can it be done without an assignment using cascades?

Answer (score 0):

I wish you could do something like this, but no, it's not currently possible with dart.

Now you could technically do this `return s.trimRight().split(' ').last.length);` but this is more expansive than computing `s.trimRight()` and saving it into a var...
`